# custom LinearLayout Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

i make a custom LinearLayout, xml error has occurred

this code is xamarin(C#) code, but xml code is like a Java. 
write the code.

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.eappandroid.phone1.OpendCheckLinearLayout
```

first, Unhandled Exception line is (in LeftDrawerMenuItemAdapter class)(in GetView)

```
convertView = ((Activity)Context).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LeftDrawerMenu_List_Item, null);
```

LeftDrawerMenu_List_Item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.eappandroid.phone1.OpendCheckLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_item_background_color_pressed"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list_item_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list_icon"
      android:layout_width="36dp"
      android:layout_height="36dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
      android:gravity="center" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list_item_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="52dp"
      android:gravity="left|center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="item"
      android:textColor="@drawable/menu_item_title_color_pressed"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/left_drawer_noti_alert"
      android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
      android:background="@drawable/menu_icon_noti_new_alert"
      android:gravity="center" />
</com.eappandroid.phone1.OpendCheckLinearLayout>
```

OpendCheckLinearLayout class

```
namespace EAppAndroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2
{


    public class OpendCheckLinearLayout : LinearLayout
    {
        private static readonly int[] STATE_MENU_OPEND = { Resource.Attribute.state_menu_opend };
        public bool menuOpen = false;



        public OpendCheckLinearLayout(Context context)
            : base(context, null)
        {

        }

        public OpendCheckLinearLayout(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attributeSet)
            : base(context, attributeSet)
        {

        }

        public OpendCheckLinearLayout(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle)
            : base(context, attributeSet, defStyle)
        {

        }



        protected override int[] OnCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)
        {
            if (menuOpen)
            {
                int[] drawableStates = base.OnCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
                MergeDrawableStates(drawableStates, STATE_MENU_OPEND);

                return drawableStates;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.OnCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
            }

        }

        public void setMenuOpen(bool menuOpen)
        {

            if (this.menuOpen != menuOpen)
            {
                this.menuOpen = menuOpen;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: This exception comes only when you add an image of large size in the background of your widgets. So try to remove all images and then run.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Also must remove , However, No error when using the default LinearLayout . So, I thought this custom layout problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace seems to be wrong.

You put `com.eappandroid.phone1.OpendCheckLinearLayout` in your xml, but in your OpendCheckLinearLayout class you have  `EAppAndroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2`, so you should probably put `com.eappandroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2.OpendCheckLinearLayout`

EDIT:

Seems that only the namespace is required in the xml, so you should put `eappandroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2.OpendCheckLinearLayout`

Comment: hi. i have tried it. but..
Unhandled Exception : Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.eappandroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2.OpendCheckLinearLayout

Comment: my package name : com.eappandroid.phone1  and  OpendCheckLinearLayout src : EAppAndroid\Protype\LeftDrawerMenu2\OpendCheckLinearLayout.cs

Comment: Maybe try also eappandroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2.OpendCheckLinearLayout or com.eappandroid.phone1.eappandroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2.OpendCheckLinearLayout

Comment: works for me : EAppAndroid.Protype.LeftDrawerMenu2.OpendCheckLinearLayout ,Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! I'll edit my answer to be more clear for future references.